# read in sequence different json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have different JSON files in my local directory and I read all of them with this code

```
path_to_json = 'C:/Users/../Desktop/NewData'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
def func(s):
    try:
        return eval(s)
    except:
        return dict()
list_of_df=[]
for i in range(len(json_files)):
    try:
        file_name = json_files[i]
        df = pd.read_json(file_name, lines=True)
        df= df[['something']]
        df = df['something'].apply(func)
        df=pd.json_normalize(df)
        df=pd.DataFrame(df[["something", "something1"]])
        df['Index'] = 'weather5' + str(6+i)
    except:
        pass
    list_of_df.append(df)
df=pd.concat(list_of_df)
df = df[['Index','something', 'something1']]
df.head()
```

The name of the JSON files that I read are `weather56, weather57, weather58, weather59, weather60, weather61`

I am using this line `df['Index'] = 'weather5' + str(6+i)` to read them properly and adjust them to a dataframe. However seem that I do not read them properly as now appears in the dataframe as:

```
Index
weather56
weather57
weather58
weather59
weather510
weather511
```

How to adjust this line `df['Index'] = 'weather5' + str(6+i)` to read the JSON files with their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Index'] = 'weather5' + str(6+i)
```

As `i` goes from 0 to 6, the corresponding values generated are going to be

```
weather56   // '5' + str(6 + 0)
weather57
weather58
weather59
weather510  // '5' + str(6 + 4) := '5' + '10'
weather511
```

If you change the line to

```
df['Index'] = 'weather' + str(56+i)
```

it should appear as -

```
weather56
weather57
weather58
weather59
weather60
weather61
```